# image loader is not showing in Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

during the button click i want to show loader. the same code is working fine in firefox but not in crome.
if i'll add confirm() same code works in crome too. is any other soln?
i donto want to us confirm() or setinterval()

```
$('#payment').on('click',function(){
    showloader();// function to show loader and disable submit button
    $.ajax({
        url: "/payments/createccajax",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: {    
                email: $('#PaymentsEmail').val(), 
        },
        success: function(response) {

        $('#jqxPopupCreditCardWindow').jqxWindow('close');// close popup
                $('#ajaxmessage').prepend(response);
        showbuttons(); // fxn to hide loader and enable the submit button
        }
    });
});
    function showloader(){
    alert('eede');
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > -1) {
        $("body").append($('<div id="imageloader" class="loader"><img id="spinner" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Spinner" /></div>'));
    } else {
        $('#imageloader').css('display', 'block');
    }   
    $('input[type=submit]').css({"opacity": ".2","cursor": "progress"});
    $('input[type=submit]').attr("onClick", "return false");
    $('input[type=submit]').prop("disabled", true);
    $('input[type=button]').css({"opacity": ".2","cursor": "progress"});
    $('input[type=button]').attr("onClick", "return false");
    $('input[type=button]').prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Comment: you have to provide showloader() code

Comment: code appears to be correct, are you using document ready?

Comment: if i am adding the function under document.ready I am getting an error
"showloader is not defined" and my loader stops working for all browser.

Comment: I am not adding function in document.ready...
i have just added the ajax code in document.ready

Comment: could you try making `async:true`